# Python interior dictionary default values

Tags: python, dictionary, counter, defaultdict

I am trying to make a dictionary of dictionaries, where the default values in the interior dictionary have a default value of `0.0`.

For example, it might look something like this: `{'Jack':{'foo':0.0, 'bar':1.4, ...}, 'Mike': {'foo':6.2, ...} }`

I want to initialize all of the words to a `0.0` value so that I can simply say:

```
for word in document:
    my_dictionary['Jack'][word] += 1.4
```

I have tried using `defaultdict(dict)` and `Counter` but I can't say for sure if those are the right strategy here.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
my_dictionary = defautltdict(lambda: defaultdict(float))
```